# jquery selecting radio button by name with an array name

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to select a radio button when changed but i get an error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [name=employment[employed]]

this is the sample of my code:

```
$('[name=employment[employed]]').change(function(){
    console.log('changed');
})
```

Comment: `[name=employment[employed]]` is not a [valid selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Please include you html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already figured it out. i just add two backslashes.
`$('[name=employment\\[employed\\]]').change(function(){
    console.log('changed');
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code is helpful.

```
$('[name=employment\\[employed\\]]').change(function(){ 
    console.log('changed'); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. just add two backslashes.

```
$('[name=employment\\[employed\\]]').change(function(){ 
    console.log('changed'); 
})
```